# Web config redirect HTTP and www needs to ignore localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Asp.Net web.config redirect rule as follows, which redirects `http` to `https` and `www` to `non-www`:

```
   <rule name="HTTPS and non-WWW only" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://woodbid.co.za/{R:1}" />
   </rule>
```

However, it needs to ignore `localhost`, but the following doesn't work because the conditions are `MatchAny`, and because it's a combined rule, using `MatchAll` will cause it to break.

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
```

How can I adjust the rule to ignore `localhost`, or can I rewrite it in some way to place it in the web.release.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the rule into two worked for me:

```
<rule name="HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://woodbid.co.za/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Non-WWW only" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." ignoreCase="true" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://woodbid.co.za/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  Add your input and pattern without negate="true" to a new rule before that one with stopProcessing and no Action.

```
<rule name="Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^localhost$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="HTTPS and non-WWW only" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(.*)$" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
     <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." ignoreCase="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://woodbid.co.za/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work for me. How would it override the other rules if they're all effectively at the some hierarchical level?  I tried changing the ordering without success.

Comment: @Savage, sorry i wasn't clear. I meant adding an entire new rule, before yours.